# Sequence to approximate square root

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

In Kreyszig *Introductory Function Analysis with Applications* theorem 9.4-2, they show the existence of the positive square root of an operator using a sequence of the form:

$$
a_0 = 0 \\
a_{n+1} = a_{n} + \frac{1}{2}(x - a_n^2)
$$

Is there a name for this sequence, or a proof that it converges to the square root of x?

Comment: That's just a particular example of Newton's method, it looks like. This was known to the Babylonians.

Comment: Wouldn't Newton's method in this case look like $a_{n+1} = a_n + \frac{x - a_n^2}{2a_n}$, if we're approximating roots for the function $f(y) = x - y^2$? I guess I'm just wondering how we can drop the $a_n$ in the denominator.

Answer (score 0):

It's a mistake. Probably meant the Newton method formula,
$$a_{n+1}=a_n + \frac{x - a_n^2}{2a_n}$$
The sequence you wrote does not converge, at least for large enough values. A numerical counterexample is sufficient to prove that it's not a reliable sequence. Say $x$ is very lage, e.g., $1000$. Then $a_1 = 500$, $a_2 = -124000$, etc. When $x$ is large and you start with $a_0 = 0$, then $a_1$ is much larger than $\sqrt x$. And as long as $|a_n| \gg \sqrt{x}$, then $|a_{n+1} - a_n| \approx a_n^2/2$ so the sequence grows almost quadratically.

Comment: In the book they seem to also be assuming $x \leq 1$. This may just be a reduced form of Newton's method.

Comment: @Mark Ah, in that case then it very likely works because $a_n$ is increasing and because you always have one extra division by a number less than one in the Newton method... So probably the Newton method sequence dominates this one.